# Angular JS get error to show after user highlights input field and doesnt enter anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have some Angular JS validation working on my wizard steps app and errors appear when the user enters a character in the input field and removes it. I am wondering how do I get the error to show after the user is on the input field and does not enter anything? (They tab onto the field and tab off without entering anything) I hope this makes sense....

```
<td>
    <label>Your Name</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required />
   <span class="error" ng-show="user.validate.step1.name.$invalid && !user.validate.step1.name.$pristine">Required Field
   </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-blur:

```
<td>
   <label>Your Name</label> 
</td>
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="blur=true" required />
   <span class="error" ng-show="user.validate.step1.name.$invalid && blur">Required Field
   </span>
```

Comment: For clarity, you might want to use a different variable name than `blur`. Took me a second to figure out what you were doing. But this should work fine, +1.

Comment: I like this, but wouldn't you have to change your 'blur' variable for each field. Would those all be going in scope?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/best way would probably by marking the control as dirty by using ng-blur:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required ng-blur="user.validate.step1.name.$dirty = true"/>
```

The next 1.3 beta version(beta 12) will have a $touched you can use to check for it, but none of the current versions have that yet.